# Node App Developer - Using SSL Locally

Tags: node.js, ssl, web-applications, https, device

I have a node server app that heavily uses WebRTC. Recently, the folks behind WebRTC have decided that it will no longer work over HTTP connections. Our live app all runs on HTTPS of course, so everything is fine there, but I am no longer able to test and/or diagnose problems locally because I cannot connect a device to the server on my local machine via HTTPS.

I have a self signed certificate, and connecting my local machine to itself via https://localhost is no problem. It's connecting iOS and Android devices to my local machine's server that is the problem.

To put it shortly: how can I allow other computers and mobile devices to connect to my local machine's node server/ip address via HTTPS?

Comment: As I recall, iOS doesn't allow self signed certs without tweaking plist files

Comment: Then I should add that I have already set NSAllowArbitraryLoads to true for this.